# Pegar classes com - (hífen)

Tags: css

Bom dia.

Hoje me deparei com um problema que não estou sabendo resolver.

Um sistema de promoções gera algumas classes pra alguns elementos em minha pagina, o problema é a forma que ele gera, ele coloca traços/hifens no nome da classe e isso parece que fica impossível de manipular.

É um sistema de promoções, onde minha equipe de marketing cria as promoções. Os nomes das promoções foram criados por exemplo, com um nome parecido com esse: **"5 camisas por 99"**.

Quando o sistema gera as flags nos produtos que fazem parte dessa promoção, ele cria um elemento **p** com a classe **5-camisas-por-99**, ficando assim:

```
<p class="5-camisas-por-99">5 camisas por 99</p>
```

O problema é que preciso estilizar isso, pegando a classe, mas o css não deixa parece eu manipular classes que possuem traços.

```css
.5-camisas-por-99 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="5-camisas-por-99">5 camisas por 99</p>
```

Tentei também fazer assim, com o seletor ^= mas sem resultados:

```css
p[class^="camisas"] {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<p class="5-camisas-por-99">5 camisas por 99</p>
```

Alguém teria alguma solução de manipular isso?

OBS:

Não sou eu o dono do backend, não posso mudar o sistema.

As promoções criadas precisam ser com os nomes assim, a equipe de marketing decidiu isso, não posso mudar. Preciso realmente manipular essa classe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é que o CSS não aceita números como nome de classe, tipo `.1 { meu css }`, mas se vc colocar `.n1 { meu css }` ou `.n-1 { meu css }` ele funcionaria.

Em todo o caso vc ainda pode selecionar por attr dessa forma `[class="5-camisas-por-99"]{ meu css }` que vai funcionar como vc pode ver abaixo

```css
[class="5-camisas-por-99"]{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="5-camisas-por-99">5 camisas por 99</p>
```

**OBS:** Essa forma que vc escreveu `p[class^="camisas"]` usando o `^` só funcionaria se a primeira string do nome da classe fosse a palavra `camisa`, mas não é, no caso é o número `5`, ai não funciona... Ou se fosse `p[class*="camisas"]` usando um `*` e não um `^` funcionaria também!

Aqui tem uma lista completa que vai te ajudar a entender os seletores css por atributo https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Seletor_de_atributos

Comment: Valeu novamente, Hugo! O ^= Seria como se fosse uma expressão regular? vou dar uma lida no artigo que me passou.

Comment: @LucasdeCarvalho de boa meu caro. Na verdade eu não manjo muito de regex para te falar com certeza que funciona igual. , mas a sintaxe parece sim, no link que deixei ai na  resposta tem umas coisas mais técnicas que pode te interessar. Vc tem vários `operator` que pode usar ali, tipo `*`, `^`, `~`, `|` e `$` cada operador desse "seleciona" as strigs do nome da classe de uma forma diferente, não sei te dizer se isso é igual no regex